# method which print distinct triples

Tags: java, algorithm

Hello I am a Java noob and I have trouble understanding this code.

Here is the code:

```
//print distinct triples (i, j, k) such that a[i] + a[j] + a[k] = 0
public static void printAll(int[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
            int k = Arrays.binarySearch(a, -(a[i] + a[j]));
            if (k > j) StdOut.println(a[i] + " " + a[j] + " " + a[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't quiet understand this line

```
int k = Arrays.binarySearch(a, -(a[i] + a[j]));
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: did you read the documentation for that method? do you know what a binary search is?

Comment: Yes I know binary search, but what makes me confused is that why use  -(a[i]+a[j]) at here. Sorry I am a beginner :(

Comment: we are looking for the `a[k]` value that verifies `a[k] + a[j] + a[i] == 0`, i.e. `a[k] = -(a[j] + a[i])` nothing else to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[...] what makes me confused is that why use `-(a[i]+a[j])` at here.*

They look for this value, since that's the only value that can make `i + j + k = 0`:

Given

```
a[i] + a[j] + a[k] = 0
```

and then solving for `a[k]` gives:

```
a[k] = -(a[i] + a[j])
```

Comment: also, `if (k > j)` is not for optimization, but to ensure uniqueness of the result. As per the loops and that condition, i<j<k.

Answer (score 0):

The binarySearch method searches for the position of the second argument (in this case, -(a[i] + a[j])) in the array provided in the first argument.  The array must be sorted.  for example:

```
int[] ia = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ];
int i = Arrays.binarySearch(ia, 6);
// i == 2, since ia[2] = 6
```